# Clean install unused ID Apple

Tags: install, macos

My dad just gave me his MacPro for me to test it, since I never used before. Since I wanted it cleaned, I follow some tutorial on the Net that said I needed to reboot it with Command+Option+R, delete the disk and reinstall it.

Now the trick part, everytime I try to do that, I get a message saying my ID Apple was never used before and won't let me to proceed.

I created my ID Apple just because the the reinstaller asked me an ID.

So, basically, I can't log into the mac since the disk was already erased and I can't reinstall it because my ID was never used before.

I have NO IDEA how to solve this. Is there any way to bypass the ID Apple problem in my case?

Comment: How old is this device?  Years ago, Apple required you to buy OSX upgrades.  The recovery boot may be attempted to validate this by way of an Apple ID.  The easiest workaround would be to find someone with a Mac, download the Install OS X from the App Store, and make a bootable USB to reinstall OS X on your laptop.

Comment: Three years, I guess. Can it be anybody with a macPro? I know somebody but I'm not sure what MacOS version he has.

Comment: I'll add an answer since a comment to explain this is too long

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to find the model.  The only Mac Pro not capable of running the latest OS is the MacPro1,1.  I think they were from 2006-7.

Older computers which existed before 'free' OSX upgrades had to purchase them via the App Store.  It's possibly trying to verify an Apple ID that was used for this.

If you have access to another Mac, you can build a bootable USB with an OSX installer.  First you need to obtain the Install OS X app. As per Apple:

> Use these steps to download the version of OS X you want to install.
>   From the Apple menu, choose App Store.  Hold the Option key and click
>   the Purchases tab. You should see the versions of OS X you've
>   previously purchased. If you don't see your purchases, log in to the
>   App Store with the ID you previously used to install OS X.  Click the
>   Install button next to the version of OS X you want to download. The
>   Mac App Store normally displays OS X as being "Installed" in the
>   purchases pane. This prevents you from downloading it when your Mac
>   already has the same version of OS X installed. When you hold the
>   Option key as you click the Purchases tab, the button to the right of
>   the item you want to download should change to say "Install". If it
>   doesn't, use Spotlight to search for "Install OS X" on your computer.
>   It's likely you already have a copy of the same OS X installer in the
>   Applications folder, or on a connected drive.

*(I'll just quickly summarize the rest; if you get this far, and have questions, just respond and we'll try our best.)*  Once you have the installer, you'll also need at least an 8 GB flash drive.  Wipe it and format as GUID and HFS.  [Then follow these instructions to create a bootable installer.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)  Once done, plug it into the Mac, hold option while booting, and select the USB drive. The rest is self explanatory.